# How do I make an edge stuck to the screen?

Tags: html, css, web, border

I was trying to make a border glued to the sides of the screen how represents the picture below :

[Picture of how i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlOWJ.png)

I have html code, but i don´t know if i´m doing in the best way. Can you guys help me?

DIV Rectangle HTMl

```
<div class="content">
    This is a rectangle!
 </div
```

> 

DIV Rectangle CSS:

```
.content {

   width:100%;
   min-height: 150%;
   border:1px solid #FFFF;
   border-width: 100%;
   background-color: #FFFF;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 50%;

}
```

It is like this:

[Picture of how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08IaN.png)

I want to remove this spacing between border and screen, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. You can remove your parent block paddings (set it to 0)
2. You can wrap your `.content` with an additional block and set its margins to negative values (adjust numbers to fit your layout):

   **.wrapper { margin: 0 -5px; }**

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block-level elements and will take the full width that is available. So, the issue isn't actually the `.content` div. It's likely that the `body` has a margin still set on it. It will probably take care of it if you add:

`body { margin: 0; }`

This is just a guess that it's on the `body`, but really it's whatever parent or ancestor has margin or padding.

Answer (score 0):

[Same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387576/css-margin-0-is-not-setting-to-0)

```
      *,html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    }
```

Hope this helps, "*" will set the whole page to 0

Comment: Thanks it worked, thanks for the attention <3